# Does difference in expected life duration between men and women have biological nature?

Tags: human-biology

It is known that men in most countries live less than women. I wonder whether it is due to different life conditions or because male and female organisms differ?

For example, I heard that testosterone may cause cardiovascular deceases. Is it true? Are there other biological mechanisms that can shorten men's lifespan?

Answer (score 2):

There are several explanations. Probably these are all true to some degree and thus combine to give the general longer life expectancy of females.

Most of these statistics are from [Annex 2 of the WHO Health Report 2004](http://www.who.int/whr/2004/annex/topic/en/annex_2_en.pdf) (found through [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_expectancy#Sex_differences))

- Males are more likely to get lung cancer, liver damage and other drug-related illnesses (implied would be that males are more often alcohol/tobacco/drug users).
- Males also die more often as a result of work-related injury, especially as soldiers
- Males are usually larger. There seems to be a small inverse correlation between size and life expectancy
- Mitochondrial DNA is passes from mother to child. As such, [mutations harmful for men are less effected by natural selection](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-19093442).
- Men have one X chromosome, while women have 2. The y chromosome is very small and contains almost no genes. Thus if there is a genetic defect on the X chromosome the female might have a healthy X chromosome to compensate while the male does not have one. Among others this makes males more likely to have [hemophilia or color blindness](http://www.cmu.edu/CSR/case_studies/women_live_longer.html).

Comment: Does it mean that hormones do not affect the lifespan?